# Discord.py allowance system

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I've implemented a banking system in my bot. I want to give an allowance to users once a week, for example.

Is there a way to do this using discord.py, or would I need the time library or something else?

Comment: Look into python scheduling libraries such as sched

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know it existed thank you :)

Comment: You can also use the tasks extension to discord.py: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're able to set a cooldown for commands using the `commands.cooldown` decorator.

It takes three args:

- The number of uses
- Over what period of time the uses are valid for before resetting
- Whether it's on a cooldown per user/guild/etc.

Here's an example for a command that's allowed to be executed once every 24 hours:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

# this decorator is saying 1 command execution per user per day (time counted in seconds)
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
async def daily(ctx):
    # do something
@daily.error
async def daily_err(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(error) # tell the user when they can next use the command
    else:
        print(error)
```

The error decorator is simply down to preference - you can create an error handler with `on_command_error` if you'd rather.

---

**References:**

- [`commands.cooldown()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)
- [`Command.error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error)
- [`on_command_error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error)
- [`Commands.CommandOnCooldown()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown) - The exception that's thrown if the user tries to run the command more than they're allowed.